# Java Mail Api MimeMessage and Multipart is not able to detect attachment if Mail comes from office O365?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-attachments, multipart, mime-message

Below is the code snippet i am trying

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                try {
                    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session, mailFileInputStream);
                    Object content=mimeMessage.getContent();
                    BodyPart messagePart = null;
                    int count = ((Multipart) content).getCount();
                    //count is always =2
                    messagePart = ((Multipart) content).getBodyPart(0);
```

I tried with messagePart = ((Multipart)content).getBodyPart(1);
 as well because count is 2 but not able to get attachement

below is the snippet of mail coming from O365 and i am passin git here as file object.

due to securtiy reason i can not paste all here.

```
Some text above here
MIME-Version: 1.0

----boundary_1_768a7606-5356-4f2e-9cb9-4bcd2d468832
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="--boundary_0_2af5fb85-1e87-4c34-86ad-3a52ef763b25"

----boundary_0_2af5fb85-1e87-4c34-86ad-3a52ef763b25
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-2022-jp"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

-- Sent by an external sender --

----boundary_0_2af5fb85-1e87-4c34-86ad-3a52ef763b25--

----boundary_1_768a7606-5356-4f2e-9cb9-4bcd2d468832
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="--boundary_2_69f808df-a154-4593-ba90-6c3a570d77c8"

----boundary_2_69f808df-a154-4593-ba90-6c3a570d77c8
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="attachment.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

encryted code is comes here

----boundary_2_69f808df-a154-4593-ba90-6c3a570d77c8--

----boundary_1_768a7606-5356-4f2e-9cb9-4bcd2d468832--
```

I need to extract the attachment.csv file

Comment: I need more detail.  What exactly does "not able to get" mean?  What happens?  What do you expect to happen?  Have you read the JavaMail FAQ?  In particular, [this entry about reading attachments](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#readattach)?  If you're using Office365, why are you reading the message content from a file?

Answer (score 0):

The message you're dealing with has a more complex structure than you're expecting.  See the [msgshow.java sample program](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) for an example of how to iterate over all the message parts and extract the "attachments".